# Does making a class NotInheritable in VB.NET offer the same (potential) compiler optimizations as sealed in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, performance, optimization, compiler-construction

I've read that making a class `sealed` in C# is advisable in high-performance scenarios because it frees the compiler to make certain optimizations (e.g., inlining property getters) that it wouldn't be able to make otherwise. Is the same true for `NotInheritable` in VB.NET? My guess would be yes, but I'm posting this question in case someone else has already investigated and happens to know the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the generated IL for `sealed` in C# is identical to `NotInheritable` in VB.NET and those potential optimizations will be done by the JIT compiler which will happen regardless of the original language.

Comment: It follows from what you're saying (I think) that the JIT compiler isn't able to determine whether a derived class exists at runtime. I can appreciate that it's not necessarily straightforward to work this out (more so for public classes whose hierarchy might cross assemblies), but isn't this the sort of thing where JIT is supposed to improve over traditional compile-time optimisation?